# Hibernate List without Lazy Object

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I am using Hibernate recently and need to display topics which has comments as its foreign key (@OneToMany)  as follows:

Topic.class

```
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "topic")
public Set<Comment> getComments() {
    return this.communityComments;
}

...
```

I use Hibernate Tools to generat the DAOs which contains:

```
public List findByExample(Topic instance) {
    try {
        List results = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria("com.some.models.Topic").add(Example.create(instance))
                .list();
        return results;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        throw re;
    }
}
```

When I get the topics using `findByExample`, a set of topics will be returned. The problem is that how can I iterate the set? When I do the following code:

```
Set<Topic> oriList = topicDAO.findByExample(OneExample);
Iterator<Topic> it = oriList.iterator();
```

It shown 'no session' exception. The reason  is that I think `oriList.iterator()` tried to access the lazy object - comments.

Is there any way so solve this problem with minimal changes?

Or is there any way to set all the comments to `null` without using iterator?

Comment: minimal changes would be to make them NOT lazy...`FetchType.EAGER`

Comment: there is an excellent blog on this specific issue , you can have a look at it here http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/04/orghibernatelazyinitializationException-Could-not-initialize-proxy-no-session-hibernate-java.html
it discusses about both easy and optimal solution

Comment: You can also set the fetch mode eager for comments collection in the criteria query setFetchMode("communityComments", FetchMode.EAGER). This will override the lazy fetch in the criteria query.

Comment: @Steven Post your stacktrace. I don't think it has anything to do with Comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here your issue is with getting session.

You should try **openSession** rather than **getCurrentSession**.

```
public List findByExample(Topic instance) {
    try {
        List results = sessionFactory.openSession()
                .createCriteria("com.some.models.Topic").add(Example.create(instance))
                .list();
        return results;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        throw re;
    }
}
```